# How to save start log and end log when using Integration Service IIB?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I'm deploying a project with IIB.
The good feature is Integration Serivce, but I dont know how to save log before and after each operation.
So can any one know how to resolve that ?
Tks !

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways in my project. Refer to the following.

Code Level

1.JavaComputeNode (Using log4j )

Flow Level

1.[TraceNode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac04840_.htm)

2.[Message Flow Monitoring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc37851_.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers there is one more option, which I often use: The [IAM3 SupportPac](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021221)

It adds a log4j-Node and also provides the possibility to log from esql and java compute nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

- You can use Log Node to create audit logging. This option only store in files and the files are not rotatives
- You can use the IBM Integrated Monitor these events to create a external flow that intercepts messages and store this message in the way you prefer